# How to make a border with 3 colors like the image uploaded below?

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

i want to make border like image below with linear gradient.
I did it with 2 colors by writing;

```
border-image:  linear-gradient(orange 50%, blue 50%) 1 100%;
```

But when i try it with 3 color it doesn't work;

```
border-image: linear-gradient(orange 0%, blue 33%, red 99%) 1 100%;
```

How can i make it?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uu6wuuty/)**

[image]

Comment: Your question is how to edit your code to get 3 colors on the border (or) how to get that image that you have added? Those are two different things.

Comment: Edited, maybe now better? @Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to have three stripes of solid colors – orange, blue, red – with abrupt transitions, as opposed to smoothened colors. To do this, you need to define each section with start and finish of indentical colors, and the end of one section having the same % as the start of the next one:

```
border-image: linear-gradient(orange 33%, blue 33%, blue 66%, red 66%) 1 100%;
```

Note that "orange 0%" and "red 100%" are automatic in this case.